# How to follow and trace executed part of code while browsing a local web application?

Tags: php, jquery, debugging, bootstrap-4, web-applications

I have this enormous local web application built with PHP, bootstrap, jQuery , ajax and MVC pattern which make it really difficult for me to know where parts of code related to a certain part of the app are, is there any way that I can track what pars of code are being executed while I'm using the web app ?

Comment: you can try to use profiler tools

Comment: which ones please ? can you name me a couple ? thanks

Comment: and please post your answer, to mark it accepted if it helps

Comment: you can just research those, you can start off with xdebug

Comment: In your jQuery code, use console.log to see when jQuery/Javascript code is executed.  You can also add HTML comments in your PHP files if they generate HTML.  That might help you see where server side includes come from.  You can even edit your CSS files by adding background colors to elements to see what CSS styles are being used and when they are being used.

Comment: @quantumPuter thanks for the answer , i know all the info you mentioned but when it comes to a very big project with thousands of files and MVC pattern it is really hard to do what you mentioned , i have no issue with front end elements but the php functions calls in deferent files that is a really pain thanks for the help again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some search I found out that what i'm looking for is called **PHP profilers** and  there is 3 types :

- ***Standard profilers (like ***Xdebug***) :***
  If you’re having a major problem with your application, standard profilers can help you get to the bottom of it.
  Standard profilers periodically record stack traces of their application.
  per line of code, and frequency of method calls.
- ***Tracing profilers (this is what I'm looking for [Z-Ray](https://www.zend.com/downloads) is a popular one)*** :
  Tracing profilers are lighter weight than standard profilers and can be used while you code.
  These are designed to catch errors and follow part of code in real time while you’re developing.
- ***Application Performance Monitoring (APM) tools*** :
  APM tools monitor your entire web stack throughout the development lifecycle. They give you basic server metrics like CPU and memory, as well as detailed, code-level insights on your application’s performance. Some APM tools also give you transaction tracing and logging metrics as well.

for me looks like [Z-Ray](https://www.zend.com/downloads) is a prefect tool to look into , It has PHP debug capabilities and It displays all the internal details of a page request, across all the PHP scripts involved in building the page. It is injected into the response coming from PHP app. Also, it is shown right in the browser that you are using for development. The good thing is that you get vastly greater insight without changing your development workflow
any other suggestions are welcomed